Trying to migrate a Hive table to an Iceberg table through Spark and getting an AnalysisException error:
The error message in question:
AnalysisException: Changing the 'storage_handler' table property is
not supported to protect against metadata corruption.

Why is this happening? I'm doing the exact query that is mentioned on the docs to run in order to create an iceberg version of the table. This is the query I'm running:
ALTER TABLE mytable
SET TBLPROPERTIES ('storage_handler'='org.apache.iceberg.mr.hive.HiveIcebergStorageHandler',
 'format-version' = '2');


I think you can't do it with ALTER. You have to create a new Iceberg table with the same schema the copy the data.

Your reference to "the doc" is not very specific. Can you add a link?

What you want to achieve can be done with migrate procedure like this:
CALL catalog_name.system.migrate('db.sample')

With your code you migrate a Hive table to Iceberg for accessing it from Hive.
